# Firebase: Retrieve Daily Active Users via API

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am wondering whether there is a way to retrieve the data that is displayed in the firebase console, such as daily user per day etc, via an API:
[image: Firebase Dashboard]

Use case is that we want to create one unified dashboard and don't want to jump between applications and give everyone access to everything.

Did I miss something in the docs?

Best

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no public API for Analytics data that you see in the console.

Your only supported option to get a hold of that data is through an [export to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7030014?hl=en).  After that, you will have access to all the raw data to build your own dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the BigQuery hint, very helpful!